# Loader on button click in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to show loader icon on button click event in Java Swing when the event starts and loader needs to be disappeared when the event is finished.

How to do achieve this ?
Currently I am doing something like this.

```java
package swing;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoaderDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("loading_icon.gif");
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER);

        label.setVisible(false);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // event start
                label.setVisible(true);

                // some operation
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // event end
                label.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Any Help ?

Comment: Did you try progress bar?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Check this out for progress bar example http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/JProgressBarDoesntUpdate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you should never do anything that would block the Event Dispatching Thread.

This will prevent you UI from been updated or the user interacting with it, normally leading the user to thinking that the application has died.

Instead, you should overload all time consuming or blocking tasks to a background thread.

The simplest solution would be use a `SwingWorker`.  This provides simple to use methods for resyncing with EDT.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LoaderDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }


                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                JButton button1 = new JButton("Load me up");

//        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("loading_icon.gif");
                final JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading... ", JLabel.CENTER);

                label.setVisible(false);
                frame.add(panel);
                panel.add(button1);
                panel.add(label);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        // event start
                        label.setVisible(true);

                        new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                                // Worken hard or hardly worken...
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void done() {
                                label.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }.execute();

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should never create, modify or interact with any UI component from any thread other then the EDT.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

Comment: It means that I initiate all the business logic functions and processing via swing worker when an event is performed and update the UI when It is done ?

Comment: Anything that might block or take a long time to run should be executed in a background thread.  `SwingWorker` just provides nice methods to allow you to easily re-sync updates to the UI